# Is there any resources to code DAO from scratch and to learn about it?

Tags: the-dao, dao

I want to learn about DAO from scratch, can anyone help me with resource to code DAO from scratch and to learn about it with the following:

**solidity, ethers.js**

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/blockchainsllc/DAO

This is a really great DAO from Scratch code but it's a bit older as they are using solidity 0.4.x versions.

If you just wanna take a look at DAO from scratch code then this is a great resource. But if you wanna build a DAO from scratch then why man why you want to recreate the wheel xD